# java - how to implement Cosine Similarity with tf*idf score of the document?

Tags: java, similarity, trigonometry, tf-idf

I have a set of documents in which I am searching for my keyword. I have calculated the tf-idf values for the keyword and all the documents. Suppose, I am storing my tf-idf value in an array for all the documents, how do I use it to calculate my cosine similarity? Any kind of help with the code appreciated!

Comment: I'll surely work. Any help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the array as a collection of [vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model), one for each document with a number of elements equal to the number of terms. To determine the similarity of two documents, you calculate the [scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_product) of the corresponding vectors in the usual manner (sum of the products of the corresponding vector components) and divide it by the product of the norms of the two vectors.

It is practical to normalize the vectors before calculating the similarities. In this case, you just use the scalar product of the document vectors, as the norms will be one.

Comment: Do i have to calculate the tf*idf for all the terms in the documents? I am just calculating the tf*idf value my keyword and the document.

Comment: You can calculate the score for whatever vectors you like. If you want to compare to a keyword, you can view it as a fictional document containing just a single term.

Comment: Oh like that! Thank you so much.